# Connected 'with it / to it'?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

> He is not to be blamed for he is in no way connected *with* it?

or

> He is not to be blamed for he is in no way connected *to* it?

When should we use *with* and when *to*?

Answer (score 1):

To me, **"connected to" is stronger and more direct while "connected with" is weaker yet more broad or indirect.**  The difference is subtle and in many cases may not have a significant difference.

This might be substantiated by [Google's Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams). The usage (these are clickable links) [**directly connected to** and **directly connected with**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=directly+connected+to%2Cdirectly+connected+with&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdirectly%20connected%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdirectly%20connected%20with%3B%2Cc0) has shown a tendency to favor the prior in recent years.  However, [**indirectly connected to** and **indirectly connected with**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=indirectly+connected+to%2Cindirectly+connected+with&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cindirectly%20connected%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cindirectly%20connected%20with%3B%2Cc0) has maintained a distinct (yet narrowing) favor for the latter.

**"Connected to"** indicates a direct link.  "Connect Part A to Part B."  "Connect the HDMI cable to one of the HDMI inputs".  "She is **connected to** the robbery" might mean a more direct connection like she was a robber or a clerk on the inside working with the robber.

**"Connected with"** indicates a relationship (which could be direct or indirect).  "She is **connected with** the robbery" might mean that at this point her actual connection is unknown.  Or it might refer to a more indirect relationship like a girlfriend who knew about it but wasn't there and didn't plan it; she might end up being called to testify but not charged.

On the other hand, if reconnaissance photos shows some unknown guy talking to two mobsters, the lead detective might bark, "I want to know every connection this guy has **to** the mob; I want to know names, places, and dates!"  Note that **"connections to"** might imply direct person-to-person connections.

As another example, suppose a suspected mobster is highly suspected to have some relationship with a local post office.  The lead detective might say, "I want to know every connection this guy has **with** that post office.  I don't care if it's his dead Aunt's Cousin's girlfriend; find out how he is connected!"

"He has **connections with** the mob" may mean some relationship direct or indirect while "he has **connections to** the mob" suggests he may directly deal with or know people in the mob.  Again, this is a subtle connotation, and may not be significant.

> He is not to be blamed for he is in no way connected with it?

This would be the idiomatically correct statement.  See Google's Ngram [way connected with it,way connected to it](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=way+connected+with+it%2Cway+connected+to+it%2C+no+way+connected+with%2C+no+way+connected+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cway%20connected%20with%20it%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cway%20connected%20to%20it%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cno%20way%20connected%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cno%20way%20connected%20to%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 0):

WARNING: the below is not something I have ever studied, but what I think is the difference.

Use "connected with" to indicate a metaphorical connection:

- The corrupt governor is connected with the mafia.
- These ideas from chemistry are connected with some other ideas in physics.

Use "connected to" to indicate a metaphorical connection or a physical connection:

- The corrupt governor is connected to the mafia.
- These ideas from chemistry are connected to some other ideas in physics.
- The monitor is connected to the computer.
- The hip bone's connected to the thigh bone.

For the metaphorical connections, I find "with" to be maybe a hair weaker than "to," but this is a gray area and you could use either. For the physical connections, I think you must use "to" but am not sure. I doubt you will confuse anyone or sound ungrammatical by switching these in any sentence.