# Is it: can be connected or can be connected to

Tags: prepositions

When I have a sentence like this:
(Port in this context is a [network port](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_(computer_networking)))

> When the port can be connected, it is assumed that the instrument is ready for the test to start.

Do I need the to in there

> When the port can be connected **to**, it is assumed that the instrument is ready for the test to start.

I would assume it is only required when I have something after the `to`.
Like Connected to WiFi.
I found [Connected 'with it / to it'?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/16679/connected-with-it-to-it) which is similar but does not answer if you can use connected without either.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably better without the "to", you usually only use "to" when you want to describe something *along* with something else, e.g.:

> You can connect the charger *to* the ipad.

Or you can describe this as something "modifying" something else.

Answer (score 1):

Without an object of what you're connecting to, the word stands alone. If you add "to", you must state what you're connecting to. So, in your example:

> When the port can be connected, it is assumed....

or

> When the port can be connected to the cable, it is assumed....,

Other examples:

> I got connected.
>
> I got connected to the Internet.

> We are connected on the organizational chart.
>
> We are connected to the same supervisor on the organizational chart.

Answer (score 0):

The original sentence is very confusing and not grammatical. Two things can be connected, or one thing can be connected *to* another thing, but one thing cannot be "connected" on its own. Adding "to" makes it better, but it still is rather convoluted.

I would re-write the sentence in the active voice:

> "When the port will accept a connection, [the user can assume/the program will assume/etc] that the the instrument is ready for the test to start."